# Make eqref work in HTML export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, html, org-ref

I'm trying to use *org-ref* to reference to equation numbers.
It works with PDF export but never works in HTML export.
In the web page it only shows a clickable `(???)` link with no destination.

I tried in various ways, using `\label{·}`, `#+label: ·`, `<<·>>`, `#+name: ·`, but I never get numbering in the HTML when using `\eqref{·}` or `eqref:·`.

I get an ineffective numbering using `[[·]]`, as the number is always 1;
although the link in the HTML points to the correct ID, clicking doesn't lead anywhere.

Is there any way to make it work as expected?

Comment: I'm getting a better picture of the problem. Equations formatted in the form `\begin{equation} \label{·}` correctly get referenced with `eqref:·`.
I'm getting problems with equations that have a `split` block inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to a bug in MathJax: see https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1020#issuecomment-71666257

There is a workaround for this: place `\label{·}` after `\end{split}` and before `\end{equation}`.